# Wordpress 4.6.1 - menu URL Uncaught Error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu

When adding this if-elseif loop to the Wordpress functions.php, I get an `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://192.168.1.1/site#menu_id    jquery.js?ver=1.12.4` error for the elseif statement, while the if statement works as expected. Why?

```
        <?php if( is_front_page() ) : ?>
        <li <?php echo $active ?>>
            <a href="#<?php echo $menu_id ?>">
        <?php echo $menu_item->title  ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php elseif( !is_front_page() ) : ?>
        <li <?php echo $active ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>#<?php echo $menu_id ?>">
        <?php echo $menu_item->title  ?>
            </a>
        </li>            
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (is_front_page()): ?>
<li <?php echo $active ?>>
    <a href="#<?php echo $menu_id ?>">
        <?php echo $menu_item->title ?>
    </a>
</li>
<?php else: ?>
<li <?php echo $active ?>>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>#<?php echo $menu_id ?>">
        <?php echo $menu_item->title ?>
    </a>
</li>            
<?php endif; ?>
```

Use **else** instead of **elseif**